# PyQt6 Application 'not responding' after closing main window on macos Monterey

Tags: python, pyqt, freeze, exit, pyqt6

I'm new to PyQt6 and have ran into an issue which makes coding very tedious: when I close the application I'm working on using CMD+Q or the menu bar, the window closes but the application/python process stays in the menu bar and stops responding. I end up having to force close it every time.

I start the program by clicking the play button in the Spyder menu bar.

How do I properly set up the application to quit? This is the relevant part of the code I'm using:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
    
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image of the app in the dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeLXt.png)

My setup:  Python | 3.10.4, PyQt6 | 6.3.2, macos Monterey 12.4

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: @musicamante added it (not sure if you are notified about post edits so I'm commenting too just to be safe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution / a workaround. Running the application through a system terminal (or telling Spyder to do it in Preferences>Run>Console) makes the program exit correctly without having to force quit it every time.